# Creating thumbnail -> ugly quality (Swift - preparingThumbnail)

Tags: swift

This is how I create a thumbnail from Data:

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)!
    .preparingThumbnail(of: .init(width: size, height: size))!

try image.pngData()!.write(to: url)
```

The `data` variable contains the original image. That looks good, but I want to create thumbnails from lists.

The `size` variable holds a value which is the **same height** as my `Image` in SwiftUI. The problem is, it looks horrible:

Thumbnail:

[image]

Original:

[image]

The 'thumbnail' is the same size as the image above, it really looks that bad on the device, it is not stretched out. What is the correct way to create a thumbnail of the same quality in iOS 15.0>?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to consider the aspect ratio as well instead of just the size? Pass in the data (your `let image = UIImage(data: data)!` and see if that works)

```
func resizeImageWithAspect(image: UIImage,scaledToMaxWidth width:CGFloat,maxHeight height :CGFloat)->UIImage? {
    let oldWidth = image.size.width;
    let oldHeight = image.size.height;
    
    let scaledBy = (oldWidth > oldHeight) ? width / oldWidth : height / oldHeight;
    
    let newHeight = oldHeight * scaledBy;
    let newWidth = oldWidth * scaledBy;
    let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,false,UIScreen.main.scale);
    
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height));
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage
}
```